# Why is Scrapy's Field a dict?

Tags: python, scrapy

basically I have a really default setup, a spider subclassed from `CrawlSpider` and an item with three fields looking like this:

```
class AppdexItem(Item):
    name = Field()
    url = Field()
    desc = Field()
```

When my spider parses a response it populates an item like this:

```
i = AppdexItem()
name = hxs.select("//h1[@class='doc-banner-title']/text()")
i['name'] = name.extract()[0]
```

Now I got confused when I read what Field actually is. This is literally [its implementation](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/item.py#L17):

```
 class Field(dict):
     """Container of field metadata"""
```

It's a plain simple `dict`. I wondered why that is and stared at the implementation for a while. It still didn't make any sense. So I ran `scrapy shell` on a page which was supposed to be parsed into an item and this is what I got:

```
In [16]: item = spider.parse_app(response)

In [17]: item.fields
Out[17]: {'desc': {}, 'name': {}, 'url': {}}

In [18]: item['name']
Out[18]: u'Die Kleine Meerjungfrau'
```

What? Either I'm doing something completely wrong (I did everything like the official tutorials and examples told me) or `Field` being a `dict` is totally pointless.

Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: Considering the fact that `dict`s are one of the most optimized data structures in Python perhaps a better question is: "Which data structure *should* Scrapy use to store field metadata?"

Comment: @bernie A `Field` is not being used as a `dict`. So it doesn't matter that `dict` as a data structure is optimized. Instead `Item` is used as a `dict` to store whatever value is assigned to whatever key you defined as a `Field` before. As far as I can see, `Item` could very well just be a `namedtuple`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Historical reasons. There used to be metadata attached to the fields which was stored in the dict. I assume a dict was used because it has a convenient (key=value) constructor. You can see that the last use of this was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/commit/951ba507f94cbdeb7b573020dc6fe730fdc61dbe). At this point it makes very little difference and it could just be a plain object (although changing could be difficult if there's still code out there which assumes it's a dict for some reason).

Answer (score 3):

Field *is* used as a dict to store metadata; one use case is to specify input and output processors for ItemLoader. Check http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors.

I personally think it'd be good for Scrapy to support plain dicts without any metadata, but that's another question.